# Selecting next radio button from selected one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have a radio button group and I want to select the one next to the selected one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next').click(function() {
    $("input[name=choice]:checked").next().click();
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="choise_1" name="choice" checked="checked" />
<label for="choise_1">One</label>

<input type="radio" id="choise_2" name="choice" />
<label for="choise_2">Two</label>

<input type="radio" id="choise_3" name="choice" />
<label for="choise_3">Three</label>

<div class="button next">SELECT NEXT</div>
```

This is what I have but it is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change in the code is that you don't have to trigger `click` to check the `radio`s, instead you can change the property `checked` with `.prop()` method.

You need [`.nextAll(':radio:first')`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

> **Description:** Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, **optionally filtered by a selector**.

Here `.nextAll(filter)` with this method you don't have to worry about if your design changes or you add another element in the list. It will always target the `:radio`s only till it shares the same parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next').click(function() {
    $("input[name=choice]:checked").nextAll(':radio:first').prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="choise_1" name="choice" checked="checked" />
<label for="choise_1">One</label>

<input type="radio" id="choise_2" name="choice" />
<label for="choise_2">Two</label>

<input type="radio" id="choise_3" name="choice" />
<label for="choise_3">Three</label>

<div class="button next">SELECT NEXT</div>
```

Comment: Don't you think `.prop('checked',true)` is better approach than `.click()` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre yeah that's right. should be that instead of click.

Answer (score 4):

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/ygwjxsvm/) (just ensure that next() is called twice since there is a label between two checkboxes)

```
$('.next').click(function() {
  $("input[name=choice]:checked").next().next().click();
});
```

[next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) just gets the immediately following sibling.

The next element in tree is **label**, so you need to use **next()** twice to get *next radio button*

Comment: i wouldn't because you gave the right solution :) but i did upvote now!

Comment: Nice, I thought it would pick the next element of its kind. Thanks