# Jump to next non-disabled radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering would it be possible to move to the next radio button

[image]
It seems like it stops there whenever I click the button.

Here's the simple fiddle that I copied from [Selecting next radio button from selected one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155261/selecting-next-radio-button-from-selected-one)

https://jsfiddle.net/5pn69jed/

```
$('.next').click(function() {
  $("input[name=choice]:checked").next().next().click(); 
});
```

Comment: Why are you not using `.nextAll()` like in the original answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code stops at `Two` because `three` is disabled.  Two.next().next() = three, but three.click() does nothing as it's disabled.

Remove the disabled from three and you'll see that it works fine.

You can use `.nextAll("input:enabled").first()` to find the next enabled input

```js
$('.next').click(function() {
  $("input[name=choice]:checked").nextAll("input:enabled").first().click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="choise_1" name="choice" checked="checked" />
<label for="choise_1">One</label>

<input type="radio" id="choise_2" name="choice" />
<label for="choise_2">Two</label>

<input type="radio" id="choise_3" name="choice" disabled="disabled" />
<label for="choise_3">(Three)</label>

<input type="radio" id="choise_4" name="choice" />
<label for="choise_3">Four</label>

<button class="next">SELECT NEXT</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It doesn't seems to work on table but I already fixed the problem.  Cheers!

Comment: Using `.next()` or `.nextAll()` will look at the *siblings*.  This was what you had in your fiddle and copied here.  If you have *different HTML* (as implied by "doesn't work on table") then (frankly, obviously) you'll need *different jquery*.  Glad you got it working for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
  var checkedRadio = $("input[name=choice]:checked");
  var enabledRadios = $("input[name=choice]:enabled");
  var index = enabledRadios.index(checkedRadio);

  if (index< enabledRadios.length - 1) {
    enabledRadios[index + 1].click();
  }
});
```

This will just find the next enabled radio button and will select the next one in the enabledRadios list.